# Is there a way to perform robust contour matching with opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using opencv 3.2.
I want to cut out a part from the outline of the object and use it as a template, and I want to find it from the query image.

for example:
[image: my matching]

I use the positional relationship between the center of gravity of the outline and the contour point as a template and I am looking for a matching part from the query image.(I think that it is a childish way)
However, as objects rotate, the number of contour points will vary, so matching may not work.

I would like advice on how to realize robust contour point matching.
I also would like to give advice on how to measure similarity.

Comment: Also have a look at [cv::matchShapes](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gaadc90cb16e2362c9bd6e7363e6e4c317)

Comment: I attempted feature detection of orb but I could not find a feature point or it was too small and it did not work. (During study)
Is there any advice on how to find places where templates match in images?